# Ajax call on change of select box, fired by keys Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, events, firefox

I have a problem with select box. I assigned an ajax handler to the event `onchange`. It works fine if you use mouse. However I need it to be working when the option is changed using keys. The options change but ajax call is not made until `select` looses focus. The problem seems to be firefox specific.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R5nvZ/)

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could assign onkeyup event to select, then listen for changes manually see code

```
$("#sel").change(function(){
  alert("hello");
});

oldval = $("#sel").val();

$("#sel").keyup(function(){
  if(oldval != $("#sel").val())
  $(this).change();
});
```

Of course it should be refined before production usage, but it is a start. BTW, if you press enter after you change the value by keyboard, change event fires up. I believe you did not press enter key. So the value is indeed unchanged, rather, it is in a state of changing. So browser does not fire change event.

I hope it will be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Up and down arrow is only used to navigate through your options but if you want to trigger them you need to press enter key.

**UPDATE**

Actually option is not yet selected  until you press enter or focus is went from select box. key event and mouse click event act little differently.